# Segment inputs with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to identify common patterns in English words, using Keras. Currently, I just put the whole word in the neural network. This is bad because only long words use the neurons on the end.

Is there a way to make predictions based on runs against several pieces of data?

What I want to do is

```
word = "check"

scores = []
for segment in binify(word, binsize=4):
    # we get " che", "chec", "heck", "eck "
    scores.append(model.predict(segment))
final_classification = mean(scores)
```

I want to be able to train a neural net (the net takes 4 characters at a time), using the function described above. How best to do this? A custom optimizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make predictions based on runs against several pieces of data?

Why do you not simply pre-process your data in the way that you need it? i.e. to split it into buckets and feed your network with the data? Actually, as you have described it in your algorithm. I do not see any necessity, that a neural network executes this step.
If you want a neural network that focuses on parts of a word, Convolutional Neural Networks are the way to go. But I think CNNs will not help you for your task.

Because if I got you right you are trying to build a kind of autocomplete (but the autocompleter will complete your input on both ends of the input word?) So the label for the input "che" is "check", right? The basic problem is that e.g. "heck" could map to check, checkpoint, heck, check-in.... So there is never a clear distinction from input to label.

I would recommend to use character embeddings as inputs, because they model the similarity of characters. As a naive approach you could also use one-hot encoded characters.
Have some fun in the hidden layers - you might use a simple fully connected Dense layer at first, you can also try an LSTM.
As labels you could use word2vec word embeddings. Therefore, as an output layer you would need 300 neurons (word2vec has a dimensionality of 300). Because it is not one hot encoded anymore - you should not use cross-entropy loss, rather square loss or something similar.

Word2vec already provides out of the box tools for comparing a given vector to similar words. This is how you would get your predicted word.